# How to use Ansible inventory variables in templates

Tags: templates, variables, ansible

Is that even possible to refer to a group variable while running a play for other group?

I have a specific case like that:

/etc/ansible/hosts

```
[group1]
server1.test.org

[group2]
server2.test.com

[group2:vars]
foo=bar
```

Running a play for group1

```
- name: test variables...
  hosts: group1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
       - debug: msg="foo={{ groups[group2].foo }}"
```

It is not working, I have tried other syntax variants without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groups don't actually have variables defined for them when the inventory gets initialized.  The hosts get a copy of what's defined for group variables.  So to do what you want, you need to read from a host.  Try this:

```
- name: test variables...
  hosts: group1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="foo={{ hostvars[groups['group2'][0]].foo }}"
```